# evil star & visualstar without moving the cursor

Tags: evil

Is it possible to do something similar to these vim commands with emacs-evil? They basically do the same thing as `*` and visualstar of vim (and evil) but they do not move the cursor to the next match.

```
" 1. get current word on the cursor's position `expand('<cword>')`
" 2. wrap it with `'\<'` and `'\>'` to mark it as a word
" 3. put it in the search register `/`
" 4. highlight the matches
noremap <silent>* :let @/ = '\<'.expand('<cword>').'\>'\|set hlsearch<CR>

" 0. call the function that does step 1~3
" 1. copy the selected region into `"` register: `execute "normal! gvy"`
" 2. escape some characters in the copied text with `\`
" 3. put it in the search register `/`
" 4. highlight the matches
vnoremap <silent>* :<C-u>call Searchgvy()\|set hlsearch<CR>
function! Searchgvy()
    " raw text on `"`, escaped text on `/`
    execute "normal! gvy"
    let l:pattern = escape(@", "\\/.*'$^~[]")
    let @/ = l:pattern
endfunction
```

Comment: I don't see why not, Emacs Lisp is a fully-featured programming language. You'll probably get more feedback if you explain what exactly that Vimscript does since this is an Emacs, not Vim Stackexchange.

Comment: @wasamasa thanks for the comment. I just updated the description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to press `*` to highlight the matches while keeping the cursor in the same place, and afterwards pressing `n` or `N` to move to next or previous match, right? You can do that with the following code:

```lisp
(defun my/star-keep-position ()
  (interactive)
  (case evil-search-module
    (evil-search (progn
                  (evil-ex-search-word-forward)
                  (evil-ex-search-previous)))
    (isearch (progn
               (evil-search-word-forward)
               (evil-search-previous)))))

(defun my/visualstar-keep-position ()
  (interactive)
  (when (region-active-p)
    (evil-visualstar/begin-search (region-beginning) (region-end) t)
    (case evil-search-module
      (evil-search (evil-ex-search-previous))
      (isearch (evil-search-previous)))))

(evil-define-key 'normal evil-motion-state-map (kbd "*") 'my/star-keep-position)
(evil-define-key 'visual evil-visualstar-mode-map (kbd "*") 'my/visualstar-keep-position)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work.
I also tried something similar to this with ``(evil-goto-mark ?`)`` to emulate ```noremap * *`` ``` but it seems to be broken too.

Comment: That's strange, it seems to work as intended for me. Did you try in normal mode? This code will only work when you press `*` in a visual mode. If that's the issue, let me know and I'll make it work with normal mode too.

Comment: Do you use `(evil-select-search-module 'evil-search-module 'evil-search)
`? Your solution works if I remove that line from my config but I need it for `evil-next-match` (aka `gn` of vim). I guess I should try reading the evil code to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Ah, I see. I edited the answer to make it work with both modules. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks a lot! Just submitted an edit request with the keep-position version of normal mode command.

Comment: @Blank_ Thanks. I just made some changes to your edit to make it work with both search modules also in normal mode.